Troubleshoot lldb on Ubuntu (WSL)
Problem Description:
I'm encountering difficulties using lldb and have been unable to identify the root cause. Here's a breakdown of my setup and the issues faced:
Setup:

Installed clang via sudo apt install clang.
Installed lldb with sudo apt-get install lldb.
Testing with a file named test.c.

#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  printf("hello world!\n");
}

Issue Encountered:
After attempting to debug using lldb, here's what happened in the shell:
$ clang -g -o test test.c
$ ./test
hello world!
$ lldb
(lldb) file ./test
Current executable set to '/mnt/c/Users/Admin/test' (x86_64).
(lldb) script
Python Interactive Interpreter. To exit, type 'quit()', 'exit()' or Ctrl-D.
>>> m = lldb.target.module['test']
>>> for i in range(m.GetNumCompileUnits()):
...   m.GetCompileUnitAtIndex(i).file.fullpath
...
'/mnt/c/Users/Admin/test.c'
>>> exit()
(lldb) breakpoint list --verbose
No breakpoints currently set.
(lldb) run
Process 576 launched: '/mnt/c/Users/Admin/test' (x86_64)
[2]  + 570 suspended  lldb

I terminated lldb after receiving no response for approximately 10 seconds.
Version Information:
$ cat /etc/*release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jammy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS"
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy

$ clang --version
Ubuntu clang version 14.0.0-1ubuntu1.1
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin

$ lldb --version
lldb version 14.0.0

$ python3 --version
Python 3.10.12

Additional Notes:
I've attempted to troubleshoot the issue according to the lldb manual without success.
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I suggest you tag this with wsl

You might also ask this on this lldb issues forum: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues.  The first step in diagnosing this is to watch the traffic between lldb & lldb-server to see where the run attempt stalled.  You turn on that log with the command log enable gdb-remote packets, then run.  To interpret the results, look here: https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb#Remote-Protocol.
